# How do I install an interior pre-hung door?

Tags: doors, installation, door-frame, interior

I have installed several pre-hung *exterior* doors using the following process:

1. Tip door into opening
2. Remove 1 screw from each hinge
3. Shim hinge side of jamb until it's plumb & flat
4. Drive a long screw through the hinge and shims into the framing
5. Shim latch side plumb & flat
6. Pull weather stripping back & drive screws through latch-side jamb into framing

I recently purchased several interior pre-hung doors. I'm good on repeating this process up until step 6. *Interior* doors don't have weather stripping to hide the screws behind.

I've considered a couple of options:

- Trim-head screws, possible countersinking a pilot hole so that the heads will be below the surface, then filling with putty, but that seems like a tremendous amount of work.
- Long brad/finish nails (I think my nailer will drive 2 or 2-1/2" nails) but I'm not sure if that's sufficient for an interior door.

What are the recommended methods of attaching the latch side of the door jamb to the framing so that the fasteners aren't visible?

Comment: I usually try to place the nails behind the door stop.

Comment: You're recommending that I pry the pre-installed stop off the jamb, nail/screw underneath, then replace it, @crip659? Might make for a good answer...

Comment: You might find the putty easier.  Those door stops are usually flimsy so care must be taken when pulling them off.  Just guessing but they seem to be about 1/2x3/4 or less.  Should be only about 1 inch finish nails holding them on.

Comment: Go on, @crip659 — that is an answer. And the stops *are* easy to pull off without breaking them.

Comment: And while nails are common practice, I like at least a few screws for the jamb, especially if the door is solid core. (Imagine a surly teen using the door at some point.)

Comment: Just to make it explicit, I do step 4.5: reinstall the door to set reveals.

Comment: You talking about the reveal between door & frame, @AloysiusDefenestrate? I do check that, too... If you're talking about some other reveal, please share more!

Comment: Yes, exactly what you’re thinking  of: the reveal between the door and the jamb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For interior doors, the door stops are usually pull off carefully.

Nails/screws can then be used to hold the door frame to the rough opening.

Doors stops are usually only held by small finishing nails.

Depending on finish, if painted the paint will probably cover the small nail holes.  Stain will probably need wood filler, but maybe not.  The holes from finishing nails maybe a 1/16 round.

Comment: Thanks. Frankly, it never occurred to me to do this. Unfortunately, I was in a big hurry to get a bathroom door hung and now I've got huge, visible screw holes to cover up. But, that's only 1 door out of 5 to hang...